# Java: cómo llamar a los números de la clase principal

Tags: java, poo

Tengo un problema con este código, la pregunta del problema es...

- Escribir un programa para encontrar el número mínimo en una lista de N enteros dados.

ENTRADA:

- La primera línea contiene el número del entero N.
- La segunda línea contiene N números separados por un solo espacio.

SALIDA:

- Imprimir el número mínimo en los N enteros dados

RESTRICCIONES DE ENTRADA:

1 < N < 10

1 < ai < 100

EJEMPLO ENTRADA:

3

5 1 4

EJEMPLO SALIDA:

1

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        PrintWriter wr = new PrintWriter(System.out);

        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().trim());

        String[] arr_arr = br.readLine().split(" ");

        int[] arr = new int[n];

        for (int i_arr = 0; i_arr < arr_arr.length; i_arr++) {
            arr[i_arr] = Integer.parseInt(arr_arr[i_arr]);
        }

        int out_ = FindIt(arr); 
        System.out.println(out_);

        wr.close();
        br.close();
    }

    static int FindIt(int[] arr) {

        boolean band = true;

        int min = 0;

        if (band == true) {
            min = num;
            band = false;
        } else if (num < min) {
            min = num;
        }

        return min;

    }
```

Hice esto, pero no sé cómo llamar a los números de la clase principal para verificar el mínimo... ¡Agradecería mucho si alguien pudiera ayudarme! Si hay algún otro error háganmelo saber!

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. Estás en el sitio en español, así que es necesario [edit] y traducir toda la pregunta, incluyendo el título.

Comment: Gracias por editar. Recuerda que el título también va en español. Pregunta: ¿cuál es la duda? Le estás entregando `arr` como parámetro a la función, ¿cuál es el problema? No es claro de qué hablas cuando dices clase principal. No hay ni una sola clase en el código, sólo dos métodos (y uno es el método main)

Comment: Si justo me di cuenta, y lo modificaste gracias por eso! Se que en la función tengo el **arr** pero ese mismo parámetro no lo puedo utilizar dentro de la función FindIt porque es un array y yo necesito un INT que los numeros recibidos por la estructura de repeticion FOR para comparar y asi de esa manera encontrar el minimo

Comment: Entonces deberías: a) recorrer el array y llamar N veces a la función findIt, ó b) recorrer el array DENTRO de findIt  y hacer las comparaciones contra cada elemento

Comment: Creo que la forma más sencilla es `int min  = Arrays.stream(arr).min().getAsInt();`.

Comment: Intente utilizando int min  = Arrays.stream(arr).min().getAsInt(); al instanciar uno de los 3 numeros automaticamente me imprime 0

Comment: ¿Al instanciar uno de los 3 números? ¿Que significa eso? Acá tienes [un ejemplo](https://onlinegdb.com/EH8DcCmL2). Acá [otro](https://onlinegdb.com/aXt6RJwTH) con `for`.

Comment: Jaime, muchisimas gracias por la ayuda y no solo a ti tambien a la comunidad! Problema resuelto, el ejemplo uno aclaro mis dudas!!